# arm-none-eabi-gcc after a small code change (++i) software does not run

Tags: gcc, arm

I use arm-none-eabi-gcc for an ARM controller (STM32). 
Problem:
After a source code change, for example ++var; the code does not run.
If I do some more modification into the same file "var2 = var1;" then code function proper.

The executable code is just shifted into the flash. 
Something with the Stack, linker, startup?!

Thanks a lot.

The both MAP files are here:

[MAP ok](http://pastebin.com/sf0XJzcW)

[MAP bad](http://pastebin.com/GSY0SZ7f)

Comment: You should provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) snippet of code, not a whole bunch of something like that

Comment: (-1) however I would clean build artifacts and make a clean new build.

Comment: A complete build does not help. It seems to be a source code problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem found.
The software works properly if it's compiled without optimizations.
With optimization for speed ON "-Os" - it does not work.

The solution was to declare one variable as "volatile".
But why the compiler sometimes optimizes it & sometimes not - I do not know.